# Can not display a form in laravel using laravel collective

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to create form in my laravel page. I use laravel collections for this, but that is not work. 
I used composer, then pasted commands to providers and alias and when I am doing this in my code:

```
       {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) }}
       echo Form::text('username');
       {{ Form::close() }}
```

I have only returned "echo..." as text.

What can I do to create my own form?

Comment: If the below posts has answered your question **please may you mark it as accepted** :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you are using double curly braces and escaping the generated form html.
Try this:

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar')) !!}
   {!! Form::text('username') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And make sure your view has a blade extension - [view_name]**.blade**.php